# Conditional probability: how do i find the conditional probability given two parameters?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

> It is known that 25% of full time workers are also students. It is also known that 64% of the population work full-time and that 22% of the population are students. If a member of the population is chosen at random, what is the probability that he or she will be a full-time worker who is not a student (rounded to 4 decimal places)?

36% are not full workers

88% are not students

i know that That the Probability of Red Fan..  P(R|F) =  P(R$\cap$ P)/P(F)

A = full time workers
B = Full time wrokers

P (A $|$ B) = 25%

P (A) = 64%

P (B) = 22%

P(B \ A) = 1 - 0.25 =  0.75

So 75% of full time workers are not students
so 75% of 64% is  P(B \ A) "P(B) not in P(A)" = $0.75 \times 0.64$ = 0.48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for $p(\neg S, F)$, which by the definition of conditional probability can be expressed as $p(\neg S, F) = p(\neg S | F)p(F)$.

Both of the quantities on the right-hand side of this equation are available from the problem, and when you plug in the correct values, the answer quickly follows.

NB that the 25% referenced in the question does *not* imply $p(S,F)=0.25$; instead, it implies that the probability that a person is a student given that they are a full-time worker. For an example of language that *would* imply $p(S,F) = 0.25$, consider, "It is known that 25 percent of people are both full-time workers and students."

Comment: What does $\neg$ mean

Comment: P(F\S) do you mean?

Comment: @Ivan [Logical negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)

Comment: Did you mean $p(\neg S, F) = p(S | F)p(F)$

Comment: Hence Did you mean $p(\neg S, F) = p(S | F)p(F)$ = 0.25*0.64 = 0.16

Comment: @Ivan I did not. For another hint, note that $p(\neg S| F) = 1 - p(S| F)$.

Comment: So... $p(\neg S, F) = p(\neg S | F)p(F)$ = (1-0.25)*0.64 = 0.48


Assuming P(S| F) = 0.25

Comment: But that's what i started with!!!! >.< lol

Comment: @Ivan Is there a reason to think this is incorrect? Does a textbook give another answer?

Comment: Ahhh P(S|F) = $\frac{P(S)P(F)}{P(F)} = P(S) $ meaning $p(\neg S, F) = p(\neg S | F)p(F)$ = (1-0.22)*0.64

Comment: Oh wait that's if they're independent variables

Comment: kk so... P(S|F) = $\frac{P(S,F)}{P(F)} = \frac{0.25}{0.64} $ meaning $p(\neg S, F) = p(\neg S | F)p(F)$ = (1-0.390625)*0.64 = 0.39

Comment: SeanEaster please reply

Comment: By "@Ivan Is there a reason to think this is incorrect? Does a textbook give another answer? " did you man i was right with 0.48? Sean please! >.<

Comment: Yes, we interpret "25% of full time workers are also students" as $P(S|F) = 0.25$, which implies $P(\neg S| F) = 0.75$. From "64% of the population work full-time," we get $P(F) = 0.64$, and from "22% of the population are students," $P(S) = 0.22$. The question is asking for $P(F, \neg S)$, which we factor as $P(\neg S|F)P(F)$, as you did in the equation that gave you $0.48$

Comment: Thank you Sean! Haha I thought because you were showing me these theory that i was originally wrong. Thanks for all your help much appreciated. The last paragraph of your OP cleared things up. =)